Are these verifications on two sentences proven sufficient so to say one is a permutation of the other?
Given a capped amount of different letters that we can use multiple times, we build sentences following these rules:

Sentences are made up of words, and words are made up of letters.

The order of words in a sentence does not matter as the order of letters in a word.

A specific letter cannot be found more than once in a word and a word can be made of a single letter.

A word cannot be written entirely with some or all letters of one other word (a word does not contain another one).

A sentence contains enough word(s) so that another one cannot be added as it would break the just above rule (saturation) (facultative ?)


Is a sentence always a letter permutation of another one if:
(A) These two sentences contain the same amount of words of a given length (for all length of word found in these sentences)
(B) Each letter of a sentence has a corresponding letter in the other sentence used in the same amount of words of a given length (for all length of word that this letter is used in)
?
If not, can you provide a counter example?
Example using 4 letters (a, b, c, d) :
The two sentences "abc abd cd", "abc acd bd" both have:

2 words of 3 letters and 1 word of 2 letters. (A)
2 letters that are each found in 2 words of 3 letters. (B)
2 letters that are each found in 1 word of 3 letter and 1 word of 2 letter. (B)

Indeed, these two sentences can be found identical using permutation of the letter "b" and "c".
I ask because if it is always the case, it would be significantly less computation hungry to verify that a sentence is a permutation of another by just looking what sentences both have up to that.

I suspect there will be counterexamples. Count-based signatures (like the degree sequence of a graph) tend not to characterize combinatorial structures up to isomorphism. Maybe there's also a counting argument to show that your proposed signature doesn't contain enough information.

Also FWIW, these sentences can be described as the maximal antichains of the power set of the set of letters.

Can you clarify that second rule? "Does not matter" for what? And I have no clue what the ending "as the order of letters in a word" clause is supposed to mean.

@Paul: The second rule states that words are commutative in sentences and letters are commutative in words.

What actions are these letters and words performing that would justify the use of "commutative"? Do you mean that two words are considered to be the same if they have the same letters, regardless of order, and two sentences are considered to be the same if they have the same words, regardless of order?

@paul yesㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤ
